# How to pass data from page to layout components using NextJS 13 app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm struggling with passing data from a child component to a layout component, specifically with rendering a "title" in the layout component dynamically. Below is a simplified version of my problem. I'm using the latest Next.js (13) app router/directory and nested layouts.

layout:

```
export default function UsersLayout({children}) {
  <>
    {/* I need the dynamic title here */}
    {children}
  </>
}
```

page:

```
export default async function Users() {
  const pageTitle = "Users" // I want to pass this string to the layout

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Didn't find any sane solution for this and had to restructure components a little bit.

Created  component with a prop title, and had to use it inside every page (leaf). Not great not terrible.

layout:

```
export default function UsersLayout({children}) {
  <>
    {children}
  </>
}
```

page:

```
export default async function Users() {
  return (
    <>
      <PageHeader title="Clients" />
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

This maybe ok for now but I am still curious how to do it, maybe there is no without global state.